# How to build and run nunit scripts integrated in visual Studio via quickbuild

Tags: nunit, quickbuild

My quick build has three steps:

1. Repository : Which is checking out the source from svn - running fine
2. Run the nunit script via devenv.com and generate the abc.xml file - **NOT WORKING**
3. Publish the report from that abc.xml - running fine with one sample xml

Could you help with this 2nd step?
i.e generating .xml automatically via quickbuild from nunit test cases.

Comment: What is the NUnit script? Does it build the production code and the test code and then run the tests? Can you present more code/scripts?

Comment: Nunit is a unit testing framework which produces a .xml file , which is taken by quick build for publishing report .

Comment: Look, you have to present a lot more information to get help on this issue. Like scripts involved etc. But normally you should be able to use the NUnit test runner executable on your test libraries. This will then produce some sort of report.

Comment: My "Quickbuild" setup is like , 1. its checking out the sources from svn 2. building through via devenv.exe 3. I want to run the nunit file via NAnt , which will produce and .XML file 4. from that .xml file the nunit report will be  published ....... step no 3 is not working ...could u please help .....    Check out the below link http://wiki.pmease.com/display/QB50/Publish+NUnit+Report

Comment: I am sorry. You are not giving enough information on the whole setup and the effort and understanding you have. There is no NUnit file! Have you ever run any unit tests? Have you ever generated a test report?

Comment: @Meilke See when we integrate NUnit in visual Studio we can run it and one NUnit test runner will appear from where we can select our test.dll file and click on run so it will start running at the end of the run we can go to Tools->Save result as xml and save the test result . So same thing I want to do dynamically via NAant , because I want to run my scripts from QuickBuild , So QuickBuild is able to checkout the sources from Svn, even I can build whatever is checked out BUT I WANT TO RUN THE TESTS AND GENERATE THE .XML FILE ,integrating NANT in Quickbuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the NUnit console runner like this:

`nunit-console /result:console-test.xml nunit.tests.dll`

More information on the runner can be found here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.2